# In Sublime text 2 php autocomplete is not working

Tags: php, sublimetext2

In my Sublime Text 2 **Autocomplete** is not working in a php file where there is no closing tag(`?>`) but it works when I give the closing tag.

As it is a good practice to avoid closing tag for getting rid of accidental spaces or other newline characters at the end of file, it is better if I don't use the closing tag.

Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: While this is perfectly on-topic here, I think you'll have a better chance of getting a useful answer by using the product's support channels, or even opening a bug report there

Comment: It isn't good practice to avoid the closing tag. You're effectively hoping that PHP will sort that all out for you, which it obviously isn't doing here. The solution is to add a closing tag.

Comment: But it may causes headers already sent error(for require or include functions) when someone will work on your code and use different code editor :(

Comment: @ShahriarMahmood Don't listen to Ben. According to PSR-2 and Zend coding standards it's good practice.

Comment: @BenStephenson From the PHP manual: ["If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file."](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your sublime **User/Preferences.sublime-settings** file add:

```
{
    "auto_complete_selector": "source, text",
}
```

This will enable auto-complete even when there is no closing PHP tag.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to force the auto-complete pop-up to appear in any filetype (tried .txt, .md, .tex, .bib, .csl, .r so far) :-)